# How to use Kedro with Pipenv?

Tags: python, pipenv, kedro

I am currently using `kedro, version 0.15.4` with `pipenv, version 2018.11.26`.

At the moment, I have to do the following if I want to use `Pipenv` (For this example, I want this project to reside in the `kedro-pipenv` directory):

1. `mkdir kedro-pipenv && cd kedro-pipenv`

   - This is needed so that the `virtualenv` created is "tied" to the project directory which only really means that it has a name that is based on the directory name from which the `pipenv install kedro` or `pipenv shell` commands are executed.
   - Unfortunately, at the moment `Pipenv` doesn't have the functionality to support custom `virtualenv` names.
2. `pipenv install kedro`

   - In my example, this generates a `virtualenv` with name `kedro-pipenv-AB9IGRnB` which resides in the following location `~/.local/share/virtualenvs/kedro-pipenv-AB9IGRnB/`
3. `pipenv shell`
4. `kedro info`

   - all is looking good, `kedro` was successfully installed in the `virualenv` handled by `Pipenv`
5. `cd .. & kedro new`

   - I navigate one directory up and provide `kedro-pipenv` as the directory name for the project. Given that the directory was already created before in step 1, this fails which is expected and I get the following message:

```
cookiecutter.exceptions.OutputDirExistsException:
Error: "/Users/xyz/projects/kedro-pipenv" directory already exists
Run with --verbose to see the full exception
Error: Failed to generate project.
```

In order to "work around" this, I do the following whilst still in the same `virtualenv` as before:

- `mv kedro-pipenv kedro-pipenv_tmp`

  - rename the existing directory
- `kedro new`

  - I provide `kedro-pipenv` as the directory name for the project.
- `mv kedro-pipenv_tmp/Pipfile* kedro-pipenv && rm -rf kedro-pipenv_tmp`

  - This step is needed so that the Python version and the single `kedro` dependency is maintained.
- `cd kedro-pipenv`
- `kedro install`
- Using `kedro build-reqs` for managing project requirements.

I am familiar with `conda` as well and it seems that it is a much cleaner way of handling environments for Kedro at the moment.

However, for most of my other projects I have been using `pyenv` in conjunction with `Pipenv` for environment and dependency management. This allows me to have environment information tied to specific project spaces by having a `Pipfile` in each of my projects' root directory.

Has anyone got any suggestions on how to improve the above workflow?

Answer (score 1):

If you need your Pipenv environment root to point to Kedro project root then your solution is probably the optimal one as things stand. If you can live with Pipenv environment root directory and Kedro project directory having different names, then you can do something like:

```
mkdir kedro-pipenv && cd kedro-pipenv
pipenv install kedro
pipenv run kedro new  # create Kedro project inside 'kedro-pipenv'
cd <project-dir>
pipenv run kedro run  # still works even in nested directory
```

As you already pointed out, it's indeed easier with `conda`, since its environment is not tied to any particular directory, unlike `pipenv`.

Hoping this helps!